# How to use an angular component for an keycloak login theme?

Tags: angular, keycloak

I would like to develop a theme for our keycloak according to our corporate design. Since the UX elements have already been implemented as angular components and are available as an npm package for our angular-based apps, I'm wondering if I can't reuse them when implementing my theme. KC themes are usually created as Freemarker templates. Is there a way to compile an angular app as a freemarker template, or to reuse the said components from the lib in a non-angular project (i.e. the freemarker templates)?

What options do I have to be able to master this task?

Comment: I am also wondering this. Did you find any solution?